# Sampling numpy array with float indices (similar to pytorch grid_sample)

Tags: python, numpy

Is there some way of sampling a numpy array with float indices, using bilinear interpolation to get the intermediate values? For example, given the 1D array:

```
arr=np.array([0,1])
```

I would like `arr[0.5]` to return `0.5`, since that index lies between 0 and 1. For a 2D example:

```
arr=np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
```

`arr[0.5, 0.5]` should return `1.5`. In pytorch this functionality is provided by [`torch.nn.grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#grid-sample), I'd like to compare performance to doing this in numpy for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know if it can be achieved with pure numpy. Personally, I use Opencv remap function as an alternative to pytorch grid_sample. It has a python binding and supports numpy array.

See [OpenCV documentation on remap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4)

Edit: Scipy interp also looks good.

[Scipy interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

Comment: would be great to hear how can you achieve that with cv2.remap

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

def grid_sample(tensor, grid):
    """Given an input and a flow-field grid, computes the output using input
    values and pixel locations from grid.

    Args:
        tensor: (N, C, H_in, W_in) tensor
        grid: (N, H_out, W_out, 2) tensor in the range of [-1, 1]

    Returns:
        (N, C, H_out, W_out) tensor
    
    See `torch.nn.functional.grid_sample`.
    """
    b, c, h, w = tensor.shape
    b_, h_out, w_out, w_ = grid.shape
    assert(b == b_ and w_ == 2)
    out = []
    for (t, g) in zip(tensor, grid):
        x_ = 0.5 * (w - 1) * (g[..., 0].reshape(-1) + 1)
        y_ = 0.5 * (h - 1) * (g[..., 1].reshape(-1) + 1)
        ix = np.floor(x_).astype(np.int32).clip(0, w - 2)
        iy = np.floor(y_).astype(np.int32).clip(0, h - 2)
        dx = x_ - ix
        dy = y_ - iy
        out.append( (1 - dx) * (1 - dy) * t[..., iy, ix]
            + dx * (1 - dy) * t[..., iy, ix + 1]
            + (1 - dx) * dy * t[..., iy + 1, ix]
            + dx * dy * t[..., iy + 1, ix + 1])
    return np.concatenate(out, axis=0).reshape(b, c, h_out, w_out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tensor = torch.randn((3, 32, 64, 64))
    grid = torch.distributions.Uniform(-1, 1).sample((3, 7, 8, 2))
    out = torch.nn.functional.grid_sample(tensor, grid, mode='bilinear',
                                          align_corners=True)

    out_np = grid_sample(tensor.numpy(), grid.numpy())

    diff = np.abs(out_np - out.numpy())
    
    print(np.max(diff))
    print(np.linalg.norm(diff))
```

The maximum differences are around 1e-7.